# move_uploaded_file() Will Not Move File

Tags: php, file, oop, model-view-controller, file-upload

I have a `class` by the name of *Input*. Within this `class` is a `function` called *iData*. This `function` is used to get file upload data, here's the function.

```
public static function iData($item, $spec = '')
{
    if (isset($_FILES[$item])) {
        if ($spec == '') {
            return $_FILES[$item];
        }else{
            $f = $_FILES[$item];
            if($f[$spec]) {
                return $f[$spec];
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But in my `controller`(By the way I'm using the `MVC` design pattern), when I tell it to move the file it doesn't. Here's my `controller`'s code.

```
if (!empty(Input::iData('file', 'name'))) {
    if (is_dir('assets/')) {
        if (move_uploaded_file(Input::iData('file', 'name'), 'assets/')) {
            echo "File was moved!";
        } else {
            echo "File failed to move!";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Please include a file to upload!";
}
```

My page `echo`s, "File failed to move!". So if the directory exists and I know that the *Input* `class` and *iData* function return the name, what is wrong?

Comment: Verify if you have the permission to put your file there.

Comment: I do have the correct permissions.

Comment: You need to use the temporary name in `$_FILES[$item]['tmp_name']` as the source in your call to `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: I'm almost positive that you're correct. I'll try that, thank you.

Comment: @Hobo Sapiens I got a new error, but  hey it's something right.Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

All is fixed. Much thanks to [Hobo Sapiens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1864610/hobo-sapiens)

I was supposed to use the `tmp_name` instead of the `name`. And also, I left the desired file name out of the `move_uploaded_file`'s second parameter.